# ViewPager doesn't update correct/ OnClickListener doesn't react

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-viewpager

)
I implemented a ViewPager in my application, and seems to work well, I use 3 XML Files for the views. on the "settings_view" there are two EditText and one Button. The Button instantiates correct, because in Debugg Mode I can see that it's not null,  but when I'm clicking on, nothing happens. To understand it better, here a code excerpt:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

LayoutInflater getView = getLayoutInflater();

        View pushview = getView.inflate(R.layout.push_view,null);      
        View listenView =getView.inflate(R.layout.listen_view, null);
        View settingsView = getView.inflate(R.layout.settings_view, null);

 login = (Button)settingsView.findViewById(R.id.ok_button1);
         login_user=(EditText)settingsView.findViewById(R.id.user1);
         login_pw=(EditText)settingsView.findViewById(R.id.pw1);


 ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);


login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

do something

```
}
        });
```

And here is my Pager Adapter:

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.settings_view;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.push_view;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.listen_view;
            break;

        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

So I cannot really figure out why it doesn't work, because it instantiates correct but the Listener doesn't react.
Is somebody here to open my eyes ?
Thanks

Update: 
These are the values I get when instantiate the Button with findviewbyid:

login=Button (id=8300....)
mAttachInfo=null
.
.
.
android.widget.Button@4050d490

Is mAttachInfo neccessary?
or something else not normal?

Update:
Ok found out, that if I'm setting up the onclick in XML and then using just the method in code, it works fine, but now it's the same Problem Spinner.setAdapter, nothing happens...

update: solved it with that link, it's briliant

http://code.google.com/p/ratebeerforandroid/source/browse/RateBeerForAndroid/src/com/ratebeer/android/gui/fragments/SearchFragment.java#486

Comment: your code says "login" is the button, and you are setting onClickListener on view named "push".
Either I am not getting what you require or you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: sorry posted the wrong code excerpt... now it's the right one

Comment: you need more information? or why doesn't anybody has a clue, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am implement onTouchListerner and then try to detect onclicklisterner.
You can refer my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13264379/968532