# Grid of Images inside ViewPager

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-viewpager, android-gridview

I am trying to implement a custom grid of images in one of my ViewPager tabs. The way I've approached this so far is putting in a GridView in xml, and inflating that through my layout. However, my onClick Listener isn't working.

Looks like that may not be the best approach because [I've asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812704/viewpager-gridview-onitemclick) on it and resolving the onClick issue doesn't seem to be practical at this point.

Is there a better way to put a custom grid of images (plus some text, etc, on the image item) inside a ViewPager and retain its clickability?

I'm trying to improve my approach.