# setOnLongClickListener doesn't work in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have used the `setOnLongClickListener()` for the *ViewPager*:

```
                viewPager.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

But the above code didn’t work in the program.
In addition to that it does not return any warning or error …
I don’t know what is wrong with it!!!

Comment: check it . [onClick on ViewPager not triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11303508/2315516)

Comment: I have seen this link before and I have used it for the click event