# Setting onClickListener on a ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I have a `ViewPager`  and I'm setting `OnClickListener` to it.

But the `ViewPager`  is not detecting the on click. Whats wrong here ?

Code:

```
  viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);        

    viewPager.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "view Pager Clicked",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

       });
```

Comment: So how do I detect a click or touch on a view pager item ? I need to hide the actionbar once I tap/click/touch on any view pager item.

Comment: may be @sunny answer will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick on ViewPager not triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243690/onclick-on-viewpager-not-triggered)

Comment: @Gissipi_453 you need to set onclick listener inside your ViewPager Item(Fragment, View... whatever), not ViewPager itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setOnClickListener` inside the adapter in `instantiateItem` method.
it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to identify touch events on your `ViewPager`, so that you can trigger an animation that hides your `ActionBar`. One method requires you create your own subclass of `ViewPager` and override `onInterceptTouchEvent`:

```
public class ABetterViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public ABetterViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ABetterViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        //Enter the code here to communicate a touch event
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

You will probably need to tailor the above to your specifications. For instance, you may only want to trigger the event once someone starts to move their finger on the screen, in which case you would use:

```
if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    //User is moving their finger over the screen
}
```

In respect to communicating the touch event from your `ViewPager` to wherever it needs to be to fire your `ActionBar` hiding animation (which I assume is the `Activity` hosting the `ViewPager`) then you can use an `interface`/`EventBus`.

Also, don't forget to replace the `ViewPager` in your `xml` `layout` file with the full name of your custom class (i.e. `com.example.mywidgets.ABetterViewPager`, or whatever)

Answer (score -3):

ViewPager is not made for `onClick`. It has `OnPageChangelistener` as below:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // this will execute when page will be selected
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```